# React Native project hanging on startup

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

So I'm going through a react native tutorial, but as soon as I got to the redux section of the tutorial, the project started hanging.  I have a sneaking suspicion it's because the code is outdated.

Here's my app.js file:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View>
          <Header title="Photos" />
          <PhotoFeed />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my reducers file:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  photos: () => []
});

export default rootReducer;
```

It's at this point that the instructor refreshes the app and checks to make sure that everything is still working, but it works for her and not for me.  Is there something I'm missing, or is this outdated code?

EDIT: Just to be sure, I tried starting the simulator from the downloaded code the instructor provides, and the simulator hangs there, too.  So it definitely seems like the code is outdated somehow.

Comment: Try to to move the `createStore` outside `render`. (Maybe in `componentDidMount`)

Comment: Thanks! However, I tried that, but the packager still hangs when I run npm run ios.